# Prove that $F(x)/F(\frac{x^3}{x + 1})$ is simple algebraic extension and find its minimal polynomial

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Prove that $F(x)/F(\frac{x^3}{x + 1})$ is simple algebraic extension and find its minimal polynomial. 
I have not seen such tasks before, can you give me a hint or right algorithm to solve it, please?

Comment: Call $y=\frac{x^3}{x+1}$. Then $x$ is a solution of the polynomial equation $x^3-yx-y=0$, with coefficients in $F(y)=F(\frac{x^3}{x+1})$.

Comment: @logarithm Am I right that $x^3 -yx- y = 0$ is the minimal polynomial too?

Comment: They would need to give more information on $F$. If, for example $y$ doens't factor then you can apply [Eisenstein criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion#Generalized_criterion) to that polynomial to conclude that it is irreducible. But it could happen that $x\in F$, for example.